# Setting passenger_nodejs do not work in Nginx server

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, passenger-nginx

I have installed a rails app with ginx/1.14.0 and passenger/6.0.6 in a Ubuntu 18.04.5. (nodejs installed with apt install nodejs). But I have to change nodejs and install with nvm. The rails app was down and I got this in the log:

```
... The application encountered the following error: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes. ...
```

I set `passenger_nodejs /home/<user>/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/bin/node;` and nothing. I set on location section and http section, after and befor `passenger_ruby` and nothing.

The only solution was with a `ln` link like https://stackoverflow.com/a/42967056/2144445 but I think this is not the best solution because What if someone change the `ln`

I do not know what I have missing can anyone help me. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `passenger`, but I had a similar problem with `foreman`. I ended up running my application using `nvm exec` like this:

```
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm exec foreman start
```

I suppose you could replace `foreman start` with any other command you are using.